# Logic for WRONG,CORRECT and UNANSWERED QUESTIONS in the quiz app android

Tags: java, android, if-statement

*Want to implement "if" condition for **WRONG,CORRECT and UNANSWERED QUESTIONS** which will display correct,wrong and score at last.App runs but its not showing the correct score for it.*

**Want to implement below format in quiz-**

```
 if(wrong_Click_radioButton) {
        wrong++;
        nextquestion++;
    }

    if(correct_Click_radioButton) {
        correct++;
        nextquestion++;
    }

    if(not_clicked_any_radioButton) {
        nextquestion++;
    }

    if(last_question_checking) {
        score display;
        switch to next android activity;
    }
```

**Want to implement the above concept.**

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int id=gr.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    rbtanswer=(RadioButton) findViewById(id);

    String answer=rbtanswer.getText().toString();


    String check="Google";
    if(answer.equals(check)) {
        score=score+1;
    }

    Intent intent=new Intent(Next1Activity.this,Next2Activity.class);
    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putInt("score",score);

    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your score is"+score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Doing your works something like this........

Comment: my above code shows correct scores ,correct wrong and right increment but it is but not working for when the user don't click any of the radio button and press next button then it shows "wrong answer" in Toast

Comment: please add more details and snapshot

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think problem here.......this part runs when did not select any radio button......so create wrong answer

Comment: not selecting any answer should be like skipping the question it should not go for wrong answer as it will decrement the score of the user.

Comment: and i have taken if (userSelection == -1)  as not selected beacause if user dont't select any radio button then radio button sends -1

Comment: Edited my question Edit-2